# Is this a right code to print x for n times?

Tags: python, function

Is this a right way to write a function that prints x for n times?
My code:

```
def funz(x,n):
    f = (x+"\n")*(n-1) + x
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sep` argument of `print`:

```
def funz(x, n):
    print(*[x]*n, sep='\n')

funz('a', 3)

# Output:
a
a
a
```

Step by step:

```
>>> print([x])
['a']

>>> print([x]*n)
['a', 'a', 'a']

>>> print(*[x]*n)
a a a

>>> print(*[x]*n, sep='\n')
a
a
a
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops are useful for tasks like this.
In this case you can do this:

```
n = int(input())
def funz(x, n):
   for _ in range(n):
      print(x)
funz('x',n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and welcome to StackOverflow! It might be helpful to add some note about the `_` variable and why we use such a funny name.